# Symlinks - performance hit?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

For deployment reasons, it is slightly easier for me to use symlinks, but these would be for all of my websites core files and configurations which will be accessed 10’s of thousands of times a day.

Am I more sensible to move the documents to the correct positions on the server (slightly more problematic deployment) rather than using symlinks for everything (slight performance degradation?)

Comment: An improvised benchmark of 10000 reads of an empty file vs a symlink to that file showed that _sometimes_ the symlink test finishes even faster than the straight-read. This result implies that other factors (other disk usage, CPU load, etc) have more impact on the performance than the symlink lookup.

Comment: For large numbers of files, adding an extra symlink -> real file will occupy one more inode (per file), which will need a slot in the OS's  inode cache, which maybe could spill the cache. But I cannot say if that would cause actual performance problems.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have created a file `testfile.txt` with 1000 lines of `blablabla` in it, and created a local symlink (`testfile.link.txt`) to it:

```
$ ls -n
total 12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000    12 2012-09-26 14:09 testfile.link.txt -> testfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 10000 2012-09-26 14:08 testfile.txt
```

(The `-n` switch is only there to hide my super-secret username.:))

And then executed 10 rounds of `cat`ing into `/dev/null` 1000 times for both files.
(Results are in seconds.)

Accessing the file directly:

```
$ for j in `seq 1 10`; do ( time -p ( for i in `seq 1 1000`; do cat testfile.txt >/dev/null; done ) ) 2>&1 | grep 'real'; done
real 2.32
real 2.33
real 2.33
real 2.33
real 2.33
real 2.32
real 2.32
real 2.33
real 2.32
real 2.33
```

Accessing through symlink:

```
$ for j in `seq 1 10`; do ( time -p ( for i in `seq 1 1000`; do cat testfile.link.txt >/dev/null; done ) ) 2>&1 | grep 'real'; done
real 2.30
real 2.31
real 2.36
real 2.32
real 2.32
real 2.31
real 2.31
real 2.31
real 2.32
real 2.32
```

Measured on (a rather old install of) Ubuntu:

```
$ uname -srvm
Linux 2.6.32-43-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 5 16:43:09 UTC 2012 i686
```

Of course it's a dumbed-down example, but based on this I wouldn't expect too much of a performance degradation when using symlinks.

I personally think, that using symlinks is more practical:

- As you said, your deployment process will be simpler.
- You can also easily use versioning and roll-back if you include some kind of timestamp or version number in the directory names (e.g. `my_web_files.v1`, `my_web_files.v2`), and use the "official" name in the symlink (e.g. `my_web_files`) pointing to the "live" version. If you want to change the version, just re-link to another versioned directory.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this. Am I reading it correctly, the symlink looks to be on average faster?

Comment: Is there some fs caching going on such that the symlink appears to be faster ? Is it worth interleaving the tests or similar ?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't state that they are _always_ faster, but yeah, in this case (and the other executions I've done while figuring out the exact command line) it is. That's an interesting result for me too, I hope some Linux/inode gurus pop in to explain it (or point out that it was pure luck).

Comment: @BrianAgnew has a good point, you should try the two tests separated more in time. Maybe even a system restart between the two (obviously not on the live server:)).

Comment: Kudos mister @battery

Comment: That benchmark will touch the disk 1-2 times and the rest is pure cache. Pointless test if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you *measured* this performance degredation ? I suspect it's hugely negligible compared to the time taken to fetch pages via the network.

Comment: No, but I wouldnt have a clue how to do this