# Overhead of symlinks (on Linux)

Tags: linux, symlink

As far as I understand the way symbolic links work, the file path is read and then followed by the operating system.

For example, for the file "myfile" in the directory "/my/very/long/path":

```
linka -> myfile
linkb -> /my/very/long/path/myfile
```

Both linka and linkb should be functionally equivalent, as they point to the same file, but linka should be faster than linkb because the OS would have to follow through /my/very/long/path/ for linkb.

Is that correct?

(In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601439/symlinks-performance-hit), the linka situation was discussed, but in my opinion, the performance degradation would be mainly caused in the linkb scenario. (In extreme cases, for example if several different file-systems and symlinked directories are involved, it may be necessary to spin up a harddisk to reach linkb but not for linka))

Comment: It's better posted in `superuser.com` or `unix.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: Why not measuring the difference on your machine?